# R: Adding Two Series to a Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Using the following website (http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html), I made the graph below:

```
mtcars$`car name` <- rownames(mtcars)  # create new column for car names
mtcars$mpg_z <- round((mtcars$mpg - mean(mtcars$mpg))/sd(mtcars$mpg), 2)  # compute normalized mpg
mtcars$mpg_type <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg_z < 0, "below", "above")  # above / below avg flag
mtcars <- mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg_z), ]  # sort
mtcars$`car name` <- factor(mtcars$`car name`, levels = mtcars$`car name`)  # convert to factor to retain sorted order in plot.

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

# Plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=`car name`, y=mpg_z, label=mpg_z)) + 
  geom_point(stat='identity', aes(col=mpg_type), size=6)  +
  scale_color_manual(name="Mileage", 
                     labels = c("Above Average", "Below Average"), 
                     values = c("above"="#00ba38", "below"="#f8766d")) + 
  geom_text(color="white", size=2) +
  labs(title="Diverging Dot Plot", 
       subtitle="Normalized mileage from 'mtcars': Dotplot") + 
  ylim(-2.5, 2.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**My Question:** I want to modify the above graph so that there are "2 dots" (green and red) on each horizontal line, representing the values of two different variables.

I created a data set for this example:

```
my_data = data.frame(var_1_col = "red", var_2_col = "green", var_1 = rnorm(8,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(8,5,1), name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))

  var_1_col var_2_col     var_1    var_2 name
1       red     green 14.726642 4.676161    A
2       red     green 11.011187 4.937376    B
3       red     green 12.418489 5.869617    C
4       red     green 21.935154 5.641106    D
5       red     green 20.209498 6.193123    E
6       red     green -5.339944 5.187093    F
7       red     green 20.540806 3.895683    G
8       red     green 21.619631 4.097438    H
```

Then, I tried to create the graph - but it comes out as empty:

```
# Plot
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=name, y=var_1, label=name)) + 
  geom_point(stat='identity', aes(col=var_1_col), size=6)  +
  scale_color_manual(name="Var 1 or Var 2", 
                     labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"), 
                     values = c("Var 1"="#00ba38", "Var 2"="#f8766d")) + 
  geom_text(color="white", size=2) +
  labs(title="Plot", 
       subtitle="Plot: Dotplot") + 
  ylim(-2.5, 2.5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**Ideally, I would like the graph to look something like this:**

[image]

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:** `var_1` could be some variable like  "average fuel price" and `var_2` could be "median fuel price"

Comment: The main reason that no points show up in your plot is from the line `ylim(-2.5, 2.5)`, which specifies the range of values (i.e., the limits for the axis) that you want to include in the graph. However, most of the points are greater than 2.5. Most of the time if I'm reproducing, then I will just run one additional line at a time. It helps to locate those kinds of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend putting the data into a long format, as it is the preference when plotting with `ggplot2`. So, I would just drop the two color columns as you can just set that in `scale_color_manual`. Then, in `aes` for `geom_point`, we can set that we want the two variables to be colored different (i.e., as their own group). Then, we can still set all of the labels, names, and colors in `scale_color_manual`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%
  select(-c(var_1_col, var_2_col)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = value, label = name)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', aes(color = variable), size = 6)  +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Var 1 or Var 2",
    labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
    values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot",
       subtitle = "Plot: Dotplot") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there a way to remove the "letter on each circle", so that they are just red or green, without the white letter? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 Yes, we can just remove the `geom_text` line. I just included it since it was in the code above, but I see now that your expected did not have it. So, I have updated to remove that (and also added the `+ theme_bw`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a question - do you know if there is any equivalent of "pivot_longer" ? Can this somehow be done with the "melt" function?

Comment: I posted a new question here about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617597/r-replacing-pivot-longer-with-melt Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 Also, I'll note that I should have loaded the `tidyr` for `pivot_longer`. So, I edited and put the library `tidyverse`, which loads `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `ggplot2`, and several others. This is probably the reason that you had an issue with it (sorry).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to modify [...], representing the values of ***two different variables***.

If you're looking to plot two different variables on the same graph (and they share a common axis like the names in this case), you can construct two separate `geom_point` arguments.

```
ggplot(my_data) +
  geom_point(aes(x=name, y=var_1, col=var_1_col)) +
  geom_point(aes(x=name, y=var_2, col=var_2_col)) +
  coord_flip()
```

You don't always have to define the axes/colors/labels in the initial `ggplot` function. By only specifying the dataset, then you can be flexible with the variables you use in the following graph-specific functions. That's how you can construct multiple graphs on one plot :)

[image: see the resultant plot here]

Comment: thank you so much! is there a way to keep the same styles?