# R: replacing "pivot_longer" with "melt"

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

In a previous question ([R: Adding Two Series to a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616536/r-adding-two-series-to-a-graph)), I learned how to make the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_data = data.frame(var_1_col = "red", var_2_col = "green", var_1 = rnorm(8,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(8,5,1), name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"))

  var_1_col var_2_col     var_1    var_2 name
1       red     green 14.726642 4.676161    A
2       red     green 11.011187 4.937376    B
3       red     green 12.418489 5.869617    C
4       red     green 21.935154 5.641106    D
5       red     green 20.209498 6.193123    E
6       red     green -5.339944 5.187093    F
7       red     green 20.540806 3.895683    G
8       red     green 21.619631 4.097438    H

my_data %>%
  select(-c(var_1_col, var_2_col)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = value, label = name)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', aes(color = variable), size = 6)  +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Var 1 or Var 2",
    labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
    values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot",
       subtitle = "Plot: Dotplot") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**My Question:** Does anyone know if it is possible to replace the `pivot_longer` function in the above code using either functions from Base R, or from `reshape`/`reshape2`?

**Here was my attempt:**

```
library(reshape)
library(reshape2)

my_data %>%
  select(-c(var_1_col, var_2_col)) %>%
  reshape2::melt(my_data, id.vars = "name", measure.vars = c("var_1", "var_2")) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = value, label = name)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', aes(color = variable), size = 6)  +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Var 1 or Var 2",
    labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
    values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot",
       subtitle = "Plot: Dotplot") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

But this produces the following error:

```
'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [3]
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course that's possible. But you are asking the wrong question. You should fix the actual issue and find out why a function from a package that is loaded is not found.

Comment: Agreed that reshape isn't better than using `tidyr::pivot_longer`. The reason it's not working is that you've used the dataset in the magrittr pipes `reshape2::melt(my_data,` rather than using the `.` to refer to the previous step in the pipe e.g. `reshape2::melt(.,`

Comment: To clarify, remove `library(reshape)` since that package is not used and replace the `melt` line with   `melt(id.vars = "name", measure.vars = c("var_1", "var_2")) %>%`    Also the code using `pivot_longer` needs `library(tidyr)` as well.

Comment: While the question shows `ggplot2` code, I've removed the tags [tag:ggplot2] and [tag:data-visualization] since the issue has to do with the reshaping code, not the vis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `pivot_longer` needs `tidyr` (i.e., `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Then, we can use `.` to pipe the `my_data` to the `melt` function (this ensures that `var_1_col` and `var_2_col` are dropped before going into `melt`). Then, we can specify the two new column names for the pivoted data (i.e., `variable` and `value`).

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%
  select(-c(var_1_col, var_2_col)) %>%
  melt(.,
       id.vars = "name",
       variable.name = "variable",
       value.name = "value") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = value, label = name)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', aes(color = variable), size = 6)  +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Var 1 or Var 2",
    labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
    values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot",
       subtitle = "Plot: Dotplot") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

Output

[image]

Or you can specify the variables in `measure.vars` as you did above, but the results are the same.

```
my_data %>%
  select(-c(var_1_col, var_2_col)) %>%
  melt(.,
       id.vars = "name",
       variable.name = "variable",
       measure.vars = c("var_1", "var_2")) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = name, y = value, label = name)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', aes(color = variable), size = 6)  +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Var 1 or Var 2",
    labels = c("Var 1", "Var 2"),
    values = c("#00ba38", "#f8766d")
  ) +
  labs(title = "Plot",
       subtitle = "Plot: Dotplot") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```